# How to insert current “login” page to certain page?

Tags: plugins, php

How can I insert the current "login" page to another page for visitors? Basically, means that if a visitor wants to view some pages, once they click to view pages and where it should display "login" page, so if they are members should be logged in then view the full page otherwise should login or register as a member. May I know how should I add the PHP code in WordPress or any other way to be able to do this?

Comment: Please edit you question, and reduce it to **one question**. We do not use questions as collections. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what you mean, but it looks like you are looking for [`is_user_logged_in`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/). You can use this test in your templates to test if a user is logged in and display information accordingly. In this fassion:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
     ... show some content ...
     }
else {
     echo "Please, login first";
     wp_login_form ($args);
     }
```

It is [`wp_login_forms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form) that will create the form for you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for the answer. I just want to ask, do I need to add the code to my theme function.php?

Comment: You would insert this in the template, like `page.php`, where you want the distinction in different content to take place.